# How can I convert csv to json file in that form?

Tags: json, csv, data-conversion

I have a Csv file like this sample:

```
0   -8,396  13,414  -35,891 39,22489124
1   -8,789  12,768  -35,891 39,09516883
2   -9,136  12,768  -35,891 39,17463722
3   -9,614  12,768  -35,891 39,2888623
4   -9,614  12,397  -36,282 39,52844709
5   -9,614  12,397  -36,282 39,52844709
```

I need to convert it to a JSON file in that form:

```
{"0": [-12.770680147058824, 1.846047794117647, -54.265625, 55.77863587895704], 
"1": [-18.388229927007298, 6.5360401459854014, -52.65647810218978, 56.156491225545878], 
"2": [-20.042738970588236, 12.849264705882353, -46.678308823529413, 52.399231898471129], 
"3": [-38.242244525547449, 15.836222627737227, -40.48357664233577, 57.897972254845804], 
"4": [-33.016879562043798, 6.3001824817518246, -38.179288321167881, 50.867127813832226]}
```

Do you have any idéa how can I do that?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to use [this tool](http://www.convertcsv.com/csv-to-json.htm) (play a little with parameters) or this javascript code:

```
csv.split(/\n/).map(l=>{[n,...a]=l.split(/ +/),out[n]=a.map(x=>+x.replace(',','.'))})
```

```js
let out={}, csv= `0   -8,396  13,414  -35,891 39,22489124
1   -8,789  12,768  -35,891 39,09516883
2   -9,136  12,768  -35,891 39,17463722
3   -9,614  12,768  -35,891 39,2888623
4   -9,614  12,397  -36,282 39,52844709
5   -9,614  12,397  -36,282 39,52844709`;

csv.split(/\n/).map(l=> {[n,...a]=l.split(/ +/),out[n]=a.map(x=>+x.replace(',','.'))});

console.log(JSON.stringify(out,0,4));
```

To download this as file use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55784435/860099)

Comment: Can you give some extra hint?

Comment: Directions: You may have to change your commas to periods in your input  depending on your locale settings. 1. Paste your data into the input area. 2.  Input Options - Field Separator is Space and Uncheck First Row is Header 3. In Step 4 template- Set  Top to be {lb}{br}, Repeating Section to be  "{f1}" : [ {f2}, {f3}, {f4}, {f5} ] and Bottom to be {br}{rb} then press Convert Csv to JSON via Template.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)

```
reduce (
    split("\n")[]           # split string into lines
  | split("\t")             # split into columns
  | select(length>0)        # eliminate blanks
  | map(gsub(",";"."))      # change decimal character
) as $r (
  {}
; .[$r[0]] = $r[1:]         # build requested result 
)
```

If `filter.jq` contains this filter and `data` contains tab-separated data

```
0   -8,396  13,414  -35,891 39,22489124
1   -8,789  12,768  -35,891 39,09516883
2   -9,136  12,768  -35,891 39,17463722
3   -9,614  12,768  -35,891 39,2888623
4   -9,614  12,397  -36,282 39,52844709
5   -9,614  12,397  -36,282 39,52844709
```

the sample data then

```
$ jq -M -R -r -s -f filter.jq data | \
  sed -e ':a' -e 'N' -e '$!ba' \
      -e 's/",\n   /",/g' \
      -e 's/\[\n   /\[/g' \
      -e 's/\n  \]/\]/g'
```

produces

```
{
  "0": [ "-8.396", "13.414", "-35.891", "39.22489124"],
  "1": [ "-8.789", "12.768", "-35.891", "39.09516883"],
  "2": [ "-9.136", "12.768", "-35.891", "39.17463722"],
  "3": [ "-9.614", "12.768", "-35.891", "39.2888623"],
  "4": [ "-9.614", "12.397", "-36.282", "39.52844709"],
  "5": [ "-9.614", "12.397", "-36.282", "39.52844709"]
}
```

Note the `sed` at the end is only to present more compact JSON for this Stack Overflow example.

Answer (score 2):

In javascript

index.html

> file as input

```
<input type="file" id="csvFileInput" onchange="handleFiles(this.files)" accept=".csv">
```

app.js

> Converting csv data to json

```
function handleFiles(files) {
   if (window.FileReader) {
    getText(files[0]);
   } else {
    alert('FileReader are not supported in this browser.');
  }
}


function getText(fileToRead) {
    var reader = new FileReader(); 
    reader.readAsText(fileToRead);
    reader.onload = loadHandler;
    reader.onerror = errorHandler;
}

 function loadHandler(event) {
    var csv = event.target.result;
    process(csv);
 }

 function process(csv) {

     // Newline split
     var lines = csv.split("\n");

     result = [];

     var headers = lines[0].split(",");

     for (var i = 1; i < lines.length - 1; i++) {

        var obj = {};

        //Comma split
        var currentline = lines[i].split(",");

        for (var j = 0; j < headers.length; j++) {
           obj[headers[j]] = currentline[j];
        }

        result.push(obj);

    }

    // OUTPUT
    console.log(result);

}

function errorHandler(evt) {
   if (evt.target.error.name == "NotReadableError") {
       alert("Canno't read file !");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's tough to answer this without knowing which language you're using but the general idea should be the same for most.
I would take the approach of reading the CSV file in line by line something like:

```
    JSONObject jsn = new JSONObject()
    for(line in csvfile){
        List lst = new ArrayList();
        String[] temp = line.split(","); //as it should be comma separated
        for(int i=1;i<temp.len;++i){
            lst.add(temp[i]);
        }
        jsn.put(temp[0], list);
    }
```

This is just a sudo code example but you should get the point.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [CSV to JSON Converter](https://toolslick.com/csv-to-json-converter) to do what you want.

Click on the **Examples** and then choose **Headerless Indexed**. That will load an example based on this problem. Then click on Convert. The main setting that drives this conversion is an **Output Type** of **Dictionary Array**.

**PS:** Your input is a bit inconsistent in terms of the delimiters (spaces ranging from 1 to 3 characters). I'm guessing it was a result of copy pasting it here and that the original file has tabs as delimiters.

**Disclaimer**: I built this tool.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't want a programming solution:

CsvCruncher takes CSV as a SQL table and let's you do a SELECT, exporting the result as CSV or JSON. github.com/OndraZizka/csv-cruncher

```
crunch -in <inputFile>.csv -out <outputFile>.json --json -sql "SELECT * FROM <inputFile>"
```

It doesn't give exactly the format you need, but then you could employ a little bit of JavaScript to change the data structure.

Answer (score 0):

**Window's** users could use the **Powershell** 3.0 console for converting `INPUTFILE.csv` to `OUTPUTFILE.json` by using the below **command.**

```
c:\> $jsonData = import-csv .\INPUTFILE.csv | ConvertTo-Json -depth 100 
                                            | Out-File .\OUTPUTFILE.json
```